# What is the difference between Lists Key/Value and a Dict Key/Value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I just couldn't find an appropriate answers.

Consider - `[A:B]` and `{A:B}` . I think, `[A:B]` pairing is not valid for Python.
Could you help me to figure it out?

Comment: There's no key-value pair in lists, they exist in dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, **Key-Value pair only exist in dictionary**. You can only insert independent elements into lists that can be indexed by integers. You can't have a key-value pair in list.

> I think, `[A:B]` pairing is not valid for Python.  Could you help me to figure it out?

Yes, that is partly correct ! You can't have a key-value pair in list. They will exists only in dictionary. The `{A:B}` is correct where `A` is the key and `B` is the value which can be accessed using `dict_name['A']` .

However, `lst[A:B]` can be considered as a slicing operation, where `lst` is any list. Slice operation is performed on Lists with the use of colon(`:`). Here, it will return you elements from index `A` to `B`. The syntax is - `list_name[start : stop : steps]`  . Eg -

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 10]

print(lst[0:3])  # prints elements from index 0 to 3-1
>>> [1, 2, 3]

print(lst[:])    # prints all the elements in the list 
>>> [1, 2, 3, 5, 10]

print(lst[::-1]) # prints all the elements in the list in reverse order
>>> [10, 5, 3, 2, 1]

print(lst[0::2]) # prints elements from index 0 with a step of 2
>>> [1, 3, 10]
```

---

The best you can do is imitate the key-value pair of dictionary into list by inserting a tuple pair or you can store key value pairs of different dictionary data structures as elements in the list.

```
lst = [{1:3,4:12},{2:3,5:6,8:9}]

print( lst[1][2]) # prints element with key 2 of dictionary at index 1
>>> 3

print(lst[0][4])  # prints element with key 4 of dictionary at index 0
>>> 12
```

The above list stores two dictionaries in it as elements. You can index the dictionary and they use it to find any key-value pair that you want.

---

In short, use **Dictionary** whenever you need to store **unordered associative data** ( *key - value* pair) (They are insertion ordered in Python 3.6+. More info - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)). Use Lists whenever you want to store an **ordered collection of items**.

Hope you understand the difference !

Comment: I totally agree that in general, you should think of dictionaries as unordered, but in Python 3.7 + they actually are guaranteed to maintain insertion order. But, for example, `{'a':1, 'b':2} == {'b':2, 'a':1}` so although they keep order, it isn't used for much internally other than how it is printed and the order that things will be iterated in.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for mentioning that. I have added a link which contains good info regarding the same

Answer (score 1):

In Python, key/value pair (a.k.a. Dictionary) is written in the following way:

```
>>> d = {'name':'John', 'age':21}
>>> d['name']
'John'
>>> d['age']
21
```

[A:B] is used to access a list/array as shown in the example below:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> a[:]     ## All items in the list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> a[2:]    ## All items beginning from index 2
['c', 'd', 'e']

>>> a[:4]    ## All items from index 0 to 3 (or 4-1) 
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> a[2:4]   ## All items from index 2 to 3 (or 4-1)
['c', 'd']
```